# A verb like molded, but for things that don't maintain their shapes

Tags: word-request

Mold usually mean form something into a particular shape, but it also implies that the shape won't lose its form for a while, but in some instances it's not the case, so the verb mold doesn't seem to be proper. What other verbs can we use?

For example:

> He ___ the jumbled plastic bags into a very long rope, which fell apart as soon as he finished.

Comment: You do use the word "form" twice in your question. Maybe you should say, "He formed ...". Or he "arranged", "assembled", "put together". You could also use the verb for whatever physical action or process he used: patted, folded, tied, glued, wove, braided ... a thesaurus might help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the creation of rope, I'd probably use "tangled" or "twisted". There are probably hundreds of other verbs that work here, some more specific than others. Maybe "lumped" would be specific enough, but **I wouldn't bother with trying to find a verb that specifically fits your description** of unsuccessful formation.

Funnily enough, you could "verb your adective", writing

> He jumbled the plastic bags into a very long rope, which fell apart as soon as he finished.